Find all value of people in a group that $3^k$ people are known
A group has $n$ people satisfied: For any $(n-2)$ people, the number of couple who know each other are equal to $3^k$. Find all value of $n$.
Initially, the most simple idea is to count the set $((A;B);C)$ such that $A$ and $B$ both know $C$
Set the number of the set is $S >0$
For every $(n-2)$ people will have $\displaystyle\binom{n}{n-2}$ ways to choose
Then for every 2 people in that group, we will choose $(A;B)$ and $C$ so $S = \displaystyle3^k\binom{n-2}{2}\binom{n}{n-2}$
But when counting in the second way, I got stuck:
For every people $C$ has $n$ ways to choose
And I don't know how to count the set $(A;B)$

Not sure the rules are clear.  Is $k$ required to be the same for all choices?  Are we to assume that the desired property holds regardless of the number of couples in the original pool who know each other?  That seems impossible...say nobody in the group knows anyone else.  There is no $k$ for which $3^k=0$.

Similarly if everyone knows everyone else....there are very few values of $n$ for which $\binom {n-2}2$ is a power of $3$.

Can you edit for clarity?  The only assumption I can think of that might lead to an interesting question is that you are looking for $n$ such that there exists some graph on $n$ vertices such that, if any specified set of $n-2$ vertices, exactly $3^k$ pairs are connected by an edge (not sure if $k$ can vary with the selection or not).  But I'm just guessing at the problem.  If you can't clarify it, I think it should be closed.  If my guess is correct...have you found some $n$ which work?  some $n$ which fail?

$k$ can vary too, and I want to find the another way to calculate the $S$ for an integer equation for $k$ and $n$

I don't know why if when I post a hard problem and I can't solve it, I put it on here and someone who find it hard like me tend to downvote, I have seen this before a lot

This is for a fixed $k$, meaning that in a set $S$ of $n-2$ people, there are $3^k$ people that know each other.  OP mentioned in the comments that "$k$ can vary too", which I take to mean that there are $3^{k_S}$ people that know each other. That requires quite a bit more analysis.
Take the standard graph theoretic interpretation, where vertices are the people and edges are a couple knowing each other.
There are ${ n \choose 2 }$ ways to pick $n-2$ people.
Each of these subgraphs have $3^k$ edges, so we have a total of $3^k { n \choose 2 } $ edges.
If a knows b, then that edge will be double-counted ${ n-2 \choose 2}$ times.
So $\frac{ 3^k { n \choose 2 } }{ { n-2 \choose 2 }} = \frac{ 3^kn(n-1)}{(n-2)(n-3) } $ is the number of edges of the graph, which has to be an integer.
Since $ \gcd(n-2, n(n-1) ) \mid 2$, so we must have $n - 2 =  2^j \times 3^l $ where $j \in \{ 0, 1 \}$.
Similarly, $ \gcd (n-3, n(n-1)) \mid 6$, so we must have $n-3 = 2^m \times 3^n$ where $m \in \{ 0, 1 \}$.
Case 1: $n-2 = 2 , n - 3 = 3^l$.
We have $n=4$ from the first equation, for which $n-3 = 1 = 3^0$.
We can construct a solution for $n=4$, where everyone knows each other, and so in any group of $n -2 = 2$ people, there is $3^0 = 1$ couple that knows each other.
Case 2: $n-2 = 3^l, n-3 = 2$
We have $ n = 5$ from the second equation, for which $n-2 \neq 3^l$. No solution.
Case 3: $n-2 = 2 \times 3^l, n - 3 = 1$.
This gives us $n = 4$, which is case 1.
Thus, the only solution is $n=4$.

Is this a double counting method? Thank you

@LụcTrườngPhát Yes. I literally followed the start of your argument. The part you were missing was "the edge will be double-counted X times".
